# How to scroll inside the table or div with Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been using Selenium to Automate Migration and I'm having a problem with scrolling inside the table. I am using selenium-chrome driver as my web driver.

This **code** did not worked for me.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Does anyone has an alternative way to scroll inside the div or the table?

Comment: Is the target element visible at all? e.g. not having `display: none;`

Comment: @SilviBurcea, nope. The elements that I wanted to click will only be visible once you scrolled down the table.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the sample project from below location and try to execute it. Here I have shown how to handle scrolling in tables.

**JAVA 1.8 or newer must be installed in your system**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ei9pKYca4923WKSk2R5suXZxqTJ0jbS-

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='dtVerticalScrollExample']")).findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));

    List<WebElement> rows = element.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    rows.forEach( row -> {
        counter++;

        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", row);
        System.out.println("Row " + counter +":");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        List<WebElement> tds = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        tds.forEach( tdEle -> {
             System.out.print(tdEle.getText() + " | ");
        });
        System.out.println("");

    });
```

Comment: While the answer might answer the question, do you mind if you edit your answer and detail how to scroll inside the table/div, based on what's inside the attached zipped project? When coming to Stack Overflow for a quick solution, you wouldn't want to download a zip just to try out a solution that might or might not work.

Comment: This might help. Thanks!

Comment: @SilviuBurcea The problem is that you cannot add the required dependencies when it comes to sharing the code. some of the dependencies are created by me :) so that is why I shared the project.

Comment: @RapperAB have you read the question? `This code did not worked for me. ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);`

Comment: It totally depends on which element that user is passing. If the user is passing table's element then definitely it won't work :)

Answer (score 0):

We can scroll inside a `table` or `div` using JavaScript. You need to pass any locator of a complete `table` or `div` and execute the following command:

```
JavaScriptExecutor js = (JavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.querySelector(<locator of div/table>).scrollTop=5000");
```

Here you can use different options instead of `scrollTop` as per your need.